# Can not scroll iframe on mobile

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe, carousel

I use iframe with image carousel. And this iframe is not scrollable on mobile. You can not scroll the page down when you touch this iframe. Is it possible to do something?
[Here is the page with such iframe.](https://cardiagram.com.ua/auto/newmodels/avtomobil-dlia-vybranykh-svitovyy-bestseler-otrymav-spetsialnu-versiiu-19543.html)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Please first ***>>>[Search for related topics on SO](https://www.google.com/search?q=scroll+iframe+mobile+site%3Astackoverflow.com)<<<*** and  if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [`[<>]`](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.

Answer (score 0):

If you see the code, you can find

```
<iframe frameborder="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" scrolling="no" allowfullscreen="true" srcdoc="" id="iframe:0" style="width: 100%; min-width: 100%; max-width: 100%; height: 100%; min-height: 100%; max-height: 100%; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; border: 0px;"></iframe>
```

There, you can see `scrolling="no"`.
This stops scrolling.

So you can replace that excluded `scrolling="no"` iframe tag.

```
<iframe frameborder="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" allowfullscreen="true" srcdoc="" id="iframe:0" style="width: 100%; min-width: 100%; max-width: 100%; height: 100%; min-height: 100%; max-height: 100%; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; border: 0px;"></iframe>
```

Comment: Thank you, Sato. The problem is that iframe is generating by script from this website: https://www.publicalbum.org/blog/embedding-google-photos-albums